# Group by and DateAdd and simple computations SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, group-by, dateadd

Here is my table and query

Table 1

```
AsOfDate                  Value
2015-06-06 11:08:21.247     5 
2015-06-06 12:08:21.247     7 
2015-06-07 10:08:21.247     8 
2015-06-08 11:08:21.247     8      
2015-06-08 10:09:21.247     9 

SELECT DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, [AsOfDate])) as DateOnly ,Min([Value])
FROM Table1 group by DateOnly
```

I am getting an error message "Invalid column name 'DateOnly'."

What would be the best way to accomplish it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your query from  :

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, [AsOfDate])) as DateOnly ,Min([Value])
FROM Table1 group by DateOnly
```

To

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, [AsOfDate])) as DateOnly ,Min([Value])
FROM Table1 group by DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, [AsOfDate]))
```

the alias `DateOnly` is known to thie level of query ( only to top of it)

Comment: Royi, that's the exact reason I asked whether downloadable? I was checking it and found good :)

Comment: Thank You Royi for making it available.

Answer (score 2):

You have to `group by DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, [AsOfDate]))`. Unfortunately you cannot use alias names in `group by` clauses.

Answer (score 2):

Here `DateOnly` is a column alias. So use the expression itself in `GROUP BY` like

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, [AsOfDate])) as DateOnly ,Min([Value])
FROM Table1 
group by DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, [AsOfDate]))
```

Answer (score 2):

You have used not the best way to cut time part from `datetime` data. If you use SQL Server version which supports `date` data type simply use `CAST(AsOfDate as date)` or you can use this: `CAST(CAST(AsOfDate as int) as datetime)`

So the query can be something like this:

```
SELECT CAST(AsOfDate as date) as DateOnly ,Min([Value])
FROM Table1
GROUP BY CAST(AsOfDate as date)
```